# How to increment Javascript variable names

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, increment

I just learned the bare minimum needed, to generate thumbnail images in my ebay + website listings.  Basically, I have up to 12 pictures in a listing, and to save having to write out the URL for each picture when I create a new listing, I've set it up that I only need to write the filename once (variable "picname"), and number of pictures (variable "picnum"), and javascript does the rest.  It works fine, but seems very long winded.

How do I shorten/optimize the code?  I'm sure some kind of loop would do the trick, but after spending the whole day searching and a lot of trial and error, I just can't figure it out.

I would like to shorten/optimize the following block of code into a loop:

```
imagenum=1;
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image1 = new Image(); image1.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb1 = new Image(); thumb1.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image2 = new Image(); image2.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb2 = new Image(); thumb2.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image3 = new Image(); image3.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb3 = new Image(); thumb3.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";;imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image4 = new Image(); image4.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb4 = new Image(); thumb4.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image5 = new Image(); image5.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb5 = new Image(); thumb5.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image6 = new Image(); image6.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb6 = new Image(); thumb6.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image7 = new Image(); image7.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb7 = new Image(); thumb7.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image8 = new Image(); image8.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb8 = new Image(); thumb8.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image9 = new Image(); image9.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb9 = new Image(); thumb9.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image10 = new Image(); image10.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb10 = new Image(); thumb10.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image11 = new Image(); image11.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb11 = new Image(); thumb11.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
if (imagenum <= picnum) {image12 = new Image(); image12.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb12 = new Image(); thumb12.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";imagenum++;}
```

I'm assuming I need something along the lines of the following:

```
for (imagenum=1; imagenum<picnum; imagenum++) {image(imagenum) = new Image(); image(imagenum).src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; thumb(imagenum) = new Image(); thumb(imagenum).src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";}
```

However I obviously have the syntax wrong as that doesn't work.  I don't know how to make the variable name increment with each cycle of the loop, and I would very much appreciate some help!

Comment: What are you doing with all those variables when you're done?

Comment: should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The variables are used to generate thumbnail images, here's an example of one of my listings with the old "long winded" version:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Thomas-Webb-Uranium-Green-Glass-Bulls-Eye-Vase-Marked-/360494856082

Sorry if I posted this in the wrong section, maybe a kind mod can move it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array. Something like this:

```
var images = [];
for (var i = 0; i < picnum; i++)
{
    images[i] = {
        Image: new Image(),
        Thumb: new Image()
    };

    images[i].Image.src = ...;
    images[i].Thumb.src = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for such tasks. So following your above code something like this might work:

```
// create the array
var images = [], thumbs = [];

// loop through all images
for ( var imagenum=1; imagenum<picnum; imagenum++) {
  images[imagenum] = new Image(); 
  images[imagenum].src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg"; 
  thumbs[imagenum] = new Image(); 
  thumbs[imagenum].src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+imagenum+").jpg";
}
```

Then you can access all you images and the respective thumbnails by,e.g., `images[1]` and `thumbs[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets to reference an array.

```
var myImages = [];
for (var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImage.src = "foo.gif";
    myImages[i] = newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 12 different vars, you can hav a single array, holding 12 different objects. Then your code should look like this:

```
var imgArray = [];
var thumbArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/auctions/2012/"+picname+" ("+i+").jpg";
    imgArray.push(img);
    var tmb = new Image();
    tmb.src = "http://www.20thcenturyglass.com/thumbs/2012/"+picname+" ("+i+").jpg";
    thumbArray.push(tmb);
}
```

PS: code is not tested to be working, but it should work...